# Tor ExitNodes as ip address is not working

Tags: exit-relays, support, configuration

Tor ExitNodes accept ISO country code or Ip address.. 
Trying to connect Tor ExitNode like..

```
   ExitNodes {X.X.0.0/16},{X.X.0.0/20} 
   StrictExitNodes 1.
```

but it's not working. so it is not possible or i'm doing wrong..

Answer (score 1):

According to the `torrc` manual page the correct syntax is

```
ExitNode X.X.0.0/16,Y.Y.Y.0/24
```

So it should work when you leave out the curly braces.

Comment: Not connected. bootstrap done 45% than Connecting.................

Comment: Are you sure that exit nodes exit in the region you provided? Can you give a real example (like what exactly you entered)?